# Repetitive try-catch blocks with Groovy 'with' closure?

Tags: groovy, lambda, closures

I have the following Groovy class:

```
@Slf4j
class WidgetService {
    WidgetDao widgetDao = new WidgetDao()

    createWidget(String name, int type) {
        try {
            widgetDao.createWidget(name, type)
        } catch(WidgetException wexc) {
            log.error(wexc)
            int x = doFizz()
            long y = doBuzz(x)
            determineHowToHandle(y)
        }
    }

    Widget getWidgetById(Long id) {
        try {
            widgetDao.getWidgetById(id)
        } catch(WidgetException wexc) {
            log.error(wexc)
            int x = doFizz()
            long y = doBuzz(x)
            determineHowToHandle(y)
        }
    }

    Widget getWidgetByName(String name) {
        try {
            widgetDao.getWidgetByName(name)
        } catch(WidgetException wexc) {
            log.error(wexc)
            int x = doFizz()
            long y = doBuzz(x)
            determineHowToHandle(y)
        }
    }

    def deleteWidget(Widget w) {
        try {
            widgetDao.deleteWidget(w)
        } catch(WidgetException wexc) {
            log.error(wexc)
            int x = doFizz()
            long y = doBuzz(x)
            determineHowToHandle(y)
        }
    }

    ...dozens of more methods with *exact* same catch block
}
```

As you can see I have a lot of duplicate, boilerplate code in my try-catch blocks. It would be nice if I could define a closure or some sort of AOP-based handler just pass the `widgetDao` method-of-interest into the closure/handler as a lambda or something similar:

```
def createWidgetClosure = { it =>
    widgetDao.createWidget(it.name, it.type)
}

def getWidgetByIdClosure = { it =>
    widgetDao.getWidgetById(it.id)
}

def tryCatchClosure = { closure =>
    try {
        closure()
    } catch(WidgetException wexc) {
        log.error(wexc)
        int x = doFizz()
        long y = doBuzz(x)
        determineHowToHandle(y)
    }
}
```

So that my `WidgetService could then look something like this:

```
@Slf4j
class WidgetService {
    WidgetDao widgetDao = new WidgetDao()

    createWidget(String name, int type) {
        tryCatchClosure(createWidgetClosure())
    }

    Widget getWidgetById(Long id) {
        tryCatchClosure(getWidgetByIdClosure())
    }

    ...dozens of more methods with *exact* same catch block
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do as below by using `tryCatchClosure` what you have now. You can even make `tryCatchClosure` a method which takes `Closure` as a parameter.

```
class WidgetService {
    WidgetDao widgetDao = new WidgetDao()

    def tryCatchClosure(Closure closure) {
        try {
            closure()
        } catch(WidgetException wexc) {
            log.error(wexc)
            int x = doFizz()
            long y = doBuzz(x)
            determineHowToHandle(y)
        }
    }

    createWidget(String name, int type) {
        tryCatchClosure {
            widgetDao.createWidget(name, type)
        } 
    }

    Widget getWidgetById(Long id) {
        tryCatchClosure {
            widgetDao.getWidgetById(id)
        }
    }

    Widget getWidgetByName(String name) {
        tryCatchClosure {
            widgetDao.getWidgetByName(name)
        }
    }

    def deleteWidget(Widget w) {
        tryCatchClosure {
            widgetDao.deleteWidget(w)
        }
    }

    // ...dozens of more methods with *exact* same catch block
}
```

Or you can also intercept each method call on `WidgetDao` by overriding `invokeMethod` method on its metaClass and handle exception (try/catch). [Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22869846/2051952).

Comment: and together with `@Delegate` all boils down to a oneliner and some error handling code.  gotta love groovy

Comment: Thanks @cfrick (+1) - can you explain what you mean by `@Delegate` and maybe provide a code example?

Comment: @cfrick good point. Can you also add comments to the gist as to where `@Delegate` kicks in (around line 24 in gist) which will make things more clear about how it functions. :)