# Repeating code using Grails domain find method

Tags: grails, dry, findby

### Initial Problem

If you have different methods that basically have only one line different, would there be a way to make it DRY by creating one method.

Example:

```
def showA( ) {
   def instance

    try {
        instance = A.findById( params.id )
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        def message = "Error while retrieving details for the given id ${ params.id }, $e"
        log.error message
        responseAsJson( 400, "Invalid id", message )
        return false
    }

    return checkAndRender(instance,  params.id);
}

def showB( ) {

       def instance

        try {
            instance = B.findByBId( params.BId )
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            def message = "Error while retrieving details for the given id ${ params.id }, $e"
            log.error message
            responseAsJson( 400, "Invalid id", message )
            return false
        }

        return checkAndRender(instance,  params.id);
    }
```

So, would there be a way to make one method and simply pass as parameter:

- The domain class
- the ID to search for

Or would it be better to pass an SQL statement instead?

### Update

Based on @dmahapatro comment, I came up with the following:

```
def showA( ) {
        def clos = {id -> A.findByAId( id ) }
        return findAndShow(clos, params.AId, params )
    }

def showB( ) {
        def clos = {id -> B.findByBId( id ) }
        return findAndShow(clos, params.BId, params )
    }

 def findAndShow(Closure closure, def id, def p)
    {
        def instance
        try {
            instance = closure(id)
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            def message = "Error while retrieving instance details for the given id ${ id }, $e"
            log.error message
            responseAsJson( 400, "Invalid Id", message )
            return false
        }

        return checkAndRender(instance,  id);
    }
```

Only remaining issues are:

- How to cleanup even further / make it cleaner.
- How to bypass warning:

  > The [findAndShow] action in [ApiController] accepts a parameter of
  >   type [groovy.lang.Closure].  Interface types and abstract class types
  >   are not supported as command objects.  This parameter will be ignored.
  >
  > ```
  >    def findAndShow(Closure closure, def id, def p)
  > ```

Comment: You can have a method which takes a closure as a parameter. [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26407700/2051952) should work. Note the usage of `tryCatchClosure` method.

Comment: @dmahapatro That was a good idea. I get an annoying warning though: `The [findAndShow] action in [ApiController] accepts a parameter of type [groovy.lang.Closure].  Interface types and abstract class types are not supported as command objects.  This parameter will be ignored.` Updating question.

       def findAndShow(Closure closure, def id, def p)

Comment: @dmahapatro If you want write your response as an answer for me to upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Make findAndShow protected instead of public, that should get rid of the warning.

Comment: @Gregor Petrin Yes this worked!

Comment: Also, to make the calling code shorter, just do everything in the closure, e.g. `findAndShow { B.findByBId(params.id) }` (Groovy implicitly returns the value of the last command) and `try { instance = closure() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should worry if you want a DRY code, is define a better exception handling. Try-catching your code everywhere to handle response to the client is not very DRY, if you put your data-access code in services, you can throw exceptions from them and use a global controller for catch the errors and handle the responses. E.g:

```
class ErrorController {

    def serverError() {
         if (request.format == 'json') {
            //Code for handling errors in json request, request.exception stores the data about the exception. 
        } else {
            //Code for handling errors in non-json request, e.g:
            render(view: 'error', model: [msg: 'Something went wrong']) //add an error view for this
        }
    }
}
```

If you like, you can also add handlers for other types of errors (403, 404, etc)

Add to UrlMappings.groovy

```
    "500"(controller: "error", action: "serverError")
```

Now you can refactor your code using your new error handling, and reflection:

Controller:

```
   class MyController {

        def myService

        def show() {
            def result = myService.myFind(params.className,params.id)
            render result as JSON //Render stuff
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
       import grails.util.Holders

       class MyService {

            def myFind(String className, Long id) {
                def result = Holders.getGrailsApplication().getDomainClass('com.mypack.'+ className).findById(id)
                if(!result) {
                    throw new ServiceException('really descriptive and usefull error msg')
                }
            }
        }
```

I defined a ServiceException class so i can add custom logic for it in my ErrorController using the instanceOf operator.

Comment: Maybe also this: http://mrhaki.blogspot.gr/2014/05/grails-goodness-exception-methods-in.html

Comment: Yes, that is a good approach too, but is only for errors in controllers, and you have to repeat that code in each of your controllers. I always try to keep my controllers as clean as posible, doing only parameters handling, and move all the data access code to services/domain classes, after all that is the idea of using the MVC pattern. Did you tried the reflection technique for your problem in particular?